# how to find this analytic function satisfying such condition

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, analyticity, holomorphic-functions

Decide whether there exists analytic $ f$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such  that $f(n) = \cos(\sqrt{n})$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I tried to raise this issue by Taylor's expansion, but I could not find a consistent result. Can someone help me?

Comment: ${}f\in \Bbb C$?

Comment: f is analytic in ℂ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The well-known Taylor series for the complex cosine is
$$
 \cos (z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} z^{2k}
$$
In particular,
$$
 \cos (\sqrt n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} n^k
$$
for all $n \in \Bbb N$. This suggests to define $f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ as
$$
  f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} z^k
$$
It remains to show (which should not be too difficult) that the radius of convergence of that series
is $\infty$, to that $f$ is an entire function with the desired property.

More generally, for any *even* entire function $g$ there is an
entire function $f$ such that $f(z^2) = g(z)$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: Many thanks. I understand.